# How can I solve non-overlap problem to calculate iou?

Tags: python, object-detection, metrics, bounding-box

I have 100 bounding boxes for both ground truth and predicted. The problem is the order of coordinates of both gt and predicted bounding boxes are different. I would like to find which order rectangles are overlap with each other. But when I run this code, it shows more than one rectangles.

for i in range (0,100):
for j in range(0,100):
pxmin,pymin,pxmax,pymax=pred['boxes'][i]
gtxmin,gtymin,gtxmax,gtymax=gt[j]

```
        ixmin=max(pxmin,gtxmin)
        ixmax=min(pxmax,gtxmax)
        iymin=max(pymin,gtymin)
        iymax=min(pymax,gtymax)
    
        parea=(pxmax-pxmin)*(pymax-pymin)
        gtarea=(gtxmax-gtxmin)*(gtymax-gtymin)
        iarea=(ixmax-ixmin)*(iymax-iymin)
        IOU=iarea/(parea+gtarea-iarea)
        if 1>IOU>0.7:
            print(i,j,np.array(IOU))
```

The output is like that:

```
0 43 0.8734822
0 44 0.72041583
0 58 0.94056284
```

for the 0th order of predicted bounding box matches with 3 ground truth boxes. But it is wrong. I checked, two of them doesnot overlap and also iou with 0.8736822 is correct overlap. So I couldnt take the highest iou score. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any coding? Otherwise, since your question is generic, you may not get any response.

Comment: I added right now @uguros